# Defining Typescript Records with React components as values

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I have a typescript project with the following definitions:

```
type WidgetType = 'NOTE' | 'TODO';
type WidgetInfo = {
   widgetType: WidgetType;
};
type Note = WidgetInfo & { text: string };
type ToDoList = WidgetInfo & { toDos: ToDo[] };
type Widget = Note | ToDoList;
```

I also have a Widget component that renders that renders the proper component for each WidgetType.

const Component = COMPONENTS[widget.widgetType];

```
const Component = COMPONENTS[widget.widgetType];

return <Component widget={widget} />;
```

I am having trouble defining the COMPONENTS Record.

I have tried the following:

```
export type WidgetProps<T extends Widget> = {
    widget: T,
};

const COMPONENTS: Record<WidgetType, React.FC<WidgetProps<Widget>>> = {
    NOTE: NoteComponent,
    TODO: ToDoListComponent,
};

const NoteComponent = ({ widget }: WidgetProps<Note>) => {...}
const ToDoListComponent = ({ widget: list }: WidgetProps<ToDoList>) => {...}
```

But typescript is complaining about the `COMPONENTS: Record` definition because `Type 'WidgetProps<Widget>' is not assignable to type 'WidgetProps<Note>'.` and the same applies to the ToDoList, although Widget is defined as `Note | ToDoList`.

What am I doing wrong? How should a scenario like this be typed?

Comment: You can't assign a wider type to a narrower type.

Comment: @kelsny is the solution in these cases be to not use a Record but instead render the appropriate component via an if/swistch statement and downcast the Widget to a Note or a ToDoList?